# Copy the files from desktop and Paste in webapplication

Tags: c#, .net

I need to Copy the files from desktop and Paste it in Web application created by asp.net with c#.
If the user copy any files from esktop, and paste the file in my webapplication output(i,e i run the application, the user enter using their login and paste some files.

then my application get the file and save it.

so, how can i get the file while user paste?

This is urgent.

Thanks and regards,
Pooja

Comment: HTML5 can do drag and drop, copy paste would require flash I guess (not sure it's possible to paste into flash, but I know it works from flash to desktop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I assume you allow user to access your application folder via network sharing, then you met need to monitor that folder so after new file added you can get them, please check this: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/use-the-net-filesystemwatcher-object-to-monitor-directory-changes-in-c/6165137
and hope it helps.

But why not you implement some upload function?